# Even Fibonacci numbers in C, conundrum

Tags: c

Problem:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I've looked up another way to do this, but I am confused as to why my method does not work. I've included the code as well as my written algorithmic process below it. No matter which span of iterations of the value k I choose (4000000 or 10), I always receive the same answer: 4200784. Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
long int sum;
sum = 0;
long int i;
i = 1;
long int j;
j = 2;
long int k;

while(k<4000000)
{   
    k = i + j;
    if(k%2==0)
        sum +=k;
    i = j;
    j = k;
    
}
printf("%d",sum);
return 0;
}

//Step 0//For the initial conditions [i][j]=[1][2]
//Step 1//Find the value of i + j.
//Step 2//Find out if the solution is even by dividing by modulus 2.
//Step 3//If even, add the solution to the sum.
//Step 4//Replace the value of i with j, and replace the value of j with the new sum.
//Repeat Steps 1-4 while i + j < 4,000,000
//1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
```

Comment: Do you really mean `i + j == k;` ?

Comment: well, `sum` is not initialized and you never assign to it

Comment: @teppic I'm confused. Isn't that what I have?

Comment: @Fredrik I tried it again and I set sum to 0. Does that initialize the variable and assign to it? Thanks guys.

Comment: @user2168665 yes that initializes it to 0

Comment: @user2168665 - yes, that's what you have -- but it's incorrect. That doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your looking for

```
sum += k;
```

not

```
k+=sum;
```

You should also fix this and place it inside your while loop

```
k = i + j;
```

Note: you should also initialize sum to 0

Comment: don't forget that `sum` is never initialized to zero

Comment: Wow, thanks @Corvin I am actually getting an answer now. It's not the right answer yet, but I will keep playing around with this. I'm glad that I was not completely crazy in my approach.

Comment: @user2168665 np, and its always nice to discover your not crazy :)

Comment: hmm, I've been trying to figure this out. It's not giving me the right value. I would figure that I should put (k = i + j); at the top of the while loop. However, I only get results when I put it right after (i = j;).

Comment: @user2168665 I have a feeling its something really simple, is it possible for you to repost your new code (or edit your existing post) or something?

Comment: @corvin, thanks for all the help man. Jim Buck discovered that I didn't initialize my k variable.

Comment: But...but...but....I...was....neither....upvoted....nor...marked...as...correct....answer?? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize your 'k' variable. On that first 'while' test, you have an undefined value for 'k', so all bets are off.